# How to add Row_Number computed column to an existing table

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, calculated-columns, row-number, identity-column

I'm using SSMS 17.4. I need to add a new column that uses Row_Number() function. But that syntax seems to be invalid

I tried three different ways, but none of them worked out.

```
ALTER TABLE MYDB.[dbo].[Table1]
ADD Rn INT NOT NULL AS (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [MyColumn] ORDER BY [MyColumn]));

ALTER TABLE MYDB.[dbo].[Table1]
ADD ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [MyColumn] ORDER BY [MyColumn]) INT NOT NULL AS Rn;


ALTER TABLE MYDB.[dbo].[Table1]
ADD Rn INT NOT NULL ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [MyColumn] ORDER BY [MyColumn]);
```

I also tried this following recommendation on this link

https://ss64.com/sql/table_a_computed.html

```
   ALTER TABLE MYDB.[dbo].[Table1]
ADD Rn INT NOT NULL ADD Rn AS ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [MyColumn] ORDER BY [MyColumn]);
```

Comment: What purpose is it serving?  There is `IDENTITY` and `SEQUENCE` that might be more suited to your need here.

Comment: Simple. You can't use a window function in a computed column.

Comment: This is almost a textbook definition of an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: You're partitioning by the same column you're ordering by? So if the column is unique you'll always get 1; if the column is not unique then you can't care about order. So what is the actual goal here? Why do you need the table to calculate this rank for you?

Comment: Hi Aaron, the column is not unique. I has duplicates

Comment: Would you consider using a view instead?

Comment: Alans, View could actually work. Thanks for your tip!

Comment: Tables do not have row numbers. They represent an unordered set.

Comment: Maybe if you can explain the requirements as to why a standard identity column, sequence or view won't work for you? It would help to generate a successful answer. Because right now this requirement doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is create a calculated column for a table that may change a number of other records, whenever a record is inserted, deleted, or updated. I do not believe any SQL engine will allow this considering the significant performance implications.

I would recommend creating a view instead that has the row number column you are looking for and then reference the view like a table.  In this case it will be dynamically calculated whenever the view is referenced.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, id id use Views and temp tables and CTE for this purpose with Subquires